# [ORA]ORA-00917: Missing Comma when inserting into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert some data from a table into an empty table, and this is how far I have come:

```
INSERT INTO T_TLF_KØ_KVARTER (TIDSPUNKT AS DATO,
 TIDSRUM AS INTERVAL,
 QUEUE AS KØ,
 SUM(TOTAL_KALD_IALT) AS KALD_I_ALT,
 SUM(ANTAL_KALD) AS KALD_INDGÅENDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_DISTRIBUERET_KALD) AS KALD_DISTRIBUEREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET) AS KALD_BESVAREDE,
 SUM(IKKE_BESVARET_KALD) AS KALD_UBESVAREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_TABTE_KALD) AS KALD_TABTE,
 SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK) AS KALD_BESVARET_U25,
 SUM(CALLBACK) AS KALD_CALLBACKS,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_KS) AS KALD_BESVARET_SC,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_SC) AS KALD_BESVARET_DI,
 SUM(BESVARET_PRI_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_PRIMÆR_SKILL,
 SUM(BESVARET_SEC_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_SEKUNDÆR_SKILL)
FROM 
    GENESYS.NYK_SEAGATE_INTERVAL_QUEUE
GROUP BY 
TIDSPUNKT,
TIDSRUM,
QUEUE
ORDER BY 
QUEUE,
TIDSRUM
```

**Edit: With SELECT**

```
INSERT INTO T_TLF_KØ_KVARTER (TIDSPUNKT AS DATO,
 TIDSRUM AS INTERVAL,
 QUEUE AS KØ,
 SUM(TOTAL_KALD_IALT) AS KALD_I_ALT,
 SUM(ANTAL_KALD) AS KALD_INDGÅENDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_DISTRIBUERET_KALD) AS KALD_DISTRIBUEREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET) AS KALD_BESVAREDE,
 SUM(IKKE_BESVARET_KALD) AS KALD_UBESVAREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_TABTE_KALD) AS KALD_TABTE,
 SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK) AS KALD_BESVARET_U25,
 SUM(CALLBACK) AS KALD_CALLBACKS,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_KS) AS KALD_BESVARET_SC,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_SC) AS KALD_BESVARET_DI,
 SUM(BESVARET_PRI_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_PRIMÆR_SKILL,
 SUM(BESVARET_SEC_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_SEKUNDÆR_SKILL)
FROM 
    GENESYS.NYK_SEAGATE_INTERVAL_QUEUE
GROUP BY 
TIDSPUNKT,
TIDSRUM,
QUEUE
ORDER BY 
QUEUE,
TIDSRUM

SELECT 
 TIDSPUNKT AS DATO,
 TIDSRUM AS INTERVAL,
 QUEUE AS KØ,
 SUM(TOTAL_KALD_IALT) AS KALD_I_ALT,
 SUM(ANTAL_KALD) AS KALD_INDGÅENDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_DISTRIBUERET_KALD) AS KALD_DISTRIBUEREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET) AS KALD_BESVAREDE,
 SUM(IKKE_BESVARET_KALD) AS KALD_UBESVAREDE,
 SUM(ANTAL_TABTE_KALD) AS KALD_TABTE,
 SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK) AS KALD_BESVARET_U25,
 SUM(CALLBACK) AS KALD_CALLBACKS,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_KS) AS KALD_BESVARET_SC,
 SUM(BESVARET_I_SC) AS KALD_BESVARET_DI,
 SUM(BESVARET_PRI_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_PRIMÆR_SKILL,
 SUM(BESVARET_SEC_SKILL) AS KALD_BESVARET_SEKUNDÆR_SKILL
FROM 
 GENESYS.NYK_SEAGATE_INTERVAL_QUEUE
GROUP BY
 TIDSPUNKT,
 TIDSRUM,
 QUEUE
ORDER BY 
 QUEUE, 
 TIDSRUM
```

Comment: Where's the SELECT? Consider creating a view  instead.

Comment: That may be the problem

Comment: A view has already been created, but I need to insert the data into a table

Comment: The INSERT syntax is `INSERT INTO targettablename (tcol1, tcol2, ...) SELECT ... FROM sourcetablename ...`.

Comment: I have added it with SELECT, still saying missing comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO T_TLF_KØ_KVARTER (DATO,
 INTERVAL,
 KØ,
 KALD_I_ALT,
 KALD_INDGÅENDE,
 KALD_DISTRIBUEREDE,
 KALD_BESVAREDE,
 KALD_UBESVAREDE,
 KALD_TABTE,
 KALD_BESVARET_U25,
 KALD_CALLBACKS,
 KALD_BESVARET_SC,
 KALD_BESVARET_DI,
 KALD_BESVARET_PRIMÆR_SKILL,
 KALD_BESVARET_SEKUNDÆR_SKILL)
SELECT 
 TIDSPUNKT,
 TIDSRUM,
 QUEUE,
 SUM(TOTAL_KALD_IALT),
 SUM(ANTAL_KALD),
 SUM(ANTAL_DISTRIBUERET_KALD),
 SUM(ANTAL_BESVARET),
 SUM(IKKE_BESVARET_KALD),
 SUM(ANTAL_TABTE_KALD),
 SUM(BESVARET_25_SEK),
 SUM(CALLBACK),
 SUM(BESVARET_I_KS),
 SUM(BESVARET_I_SC),
 SUM(BESVARET_PRI_SKILL),
 SUM(BESVARET_SEC_SKILL)
FROM 
 GENESYS.NYK_SEAGATE_INTERVAL_QUEUE
GROUP BY
 TIDSPUNKT,
 TIDSRUM,
 QUEUE
```

Comment: Thank you alot, that fixed it!

Comment: Great @SteveHoff, don't forget to tick the answered option now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO destination_table (col1,col2--coln)
SELECT col1,col2---coln FROM source_table
WHERE condition; --if any
```

but you are using aggregation (`SUM(TOTAL_KALD_IALT) AS KALD_I_ALT`) in place of column name in your query